# Creating Url Rewrite to a domain - ASP.NET \ IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 with IIS 7 with the URL Rewrite Module 2.0 installed.

When I create the first test rewrite rule:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Test rule1" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                <match url="w/123/test" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id=123" />
            </rule>           
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

It works perfectly (http://www.myapp.com/w/123/test -> http://www.myapp.com/article.aspx?id=123).

BUT, when I try to use it on a domain that I own, it doesn't work. I assume that something in my syntax is wrong. Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
            <rule name="Test Rule2" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                <match url="http://www.my-domain.com" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id=123" />
            </rule>
```

When I try to browse `http://www.my-domain.com` I expect to be redirected to the `article.aspx` page, which I don't, I just get 404 page not found.

How should I write a rule for a domain and not for a path ?

Thanks in advance, Gal.

Comment: nope, still 404. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are relative to the place where the web.config lives. You don't need to specify any domain for your rule. The input for your /> is going to be always the URL Path without the query string and without leading slash. That means, if you request "http://www.my-domain.com/" the input is going to be "". If you request "http://www.my-domain.com/w/123/test", the input would be "w/123/test".

If you just browse to http://www.my-domain.com/" the "Default Document" module in IIS will try to rewrite your request to something like http://www.my-domain.com/default.html" and that won't match your rule. Make sure to disable default document module.

If that doesn't work, URL Rewrite has a tracing feature where you can see step-by-step the workflow:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/

N.B. For server rules, the input URL includes leading slash always.